# Deployment is showing jar errors which is already added

Tags: java, build, jar, ant

I have added a jsch-0.1.55.jar in my project but while deploying the project i am getting the error that the import are not working

[image: project build to deploy]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

added the jar entry in the build file